# How to enhance Eclipse JPA validation to include Oracle specific functions?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, named-query

When creating a named query where I use the NVL function from Oracle Eclipse shows a validation error:

```
"The identification variable 'NVL' is not in the FROM clause".
```

Example query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "TEST", query = "select c from Case c order by NVL(c.caseId, 999999)")
```

I did add a Oracle Data Source to the Project but error remains.

Is there a way to enhance the Eclipse JPA validation to include Oracle specific functions?

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: I have Added an example query.

Comment: Is your table really named Case? It is a keyword.

Comment: No the table is not but the jpa entity is. The table is named "FALL" that is case in German and I can't refactor that.

Comment: As a workaround I have changed the validation of "Invalid or incomplete JQL queries" from "Error" to "Warning" (JPA -> Errors/warnings -> Queries and generators)